# Removing minimally informative bits

Tags: correlation, compression

Each sample in my data set is an $N$-bit bit-vector (say $N$=200). The bits in each sample are not uncorreleated within the sample.

I built a matrix $S_{N \times N}$ with each $s_{ij}$ being the proportion of samples where the $i$-th bit and the $j$-th bit were identical. This is a symmetric similarity matrix (obviously, with $1$s on the diagonal).

Now I want to throw some of the bits away with as little loss of information of possible.
What is the best way to choose $K$ bits, i.e. $K$ columns+rows of $S$, that when removed, the data-set retains as much of its discrimination as before.

In other words, how do I choose the top $K$ bits to remove, that can be best predicted by the remaining bits for each sample.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but it seems to me that the best answer would rest somewhat in the prediction approach you intend to use.  Maybe you could add some details about that?  You might also try on another stack exchange where people might be versed in basic file compression approaches.

Comment: I'm not really interested in restoring the removed bits. I'm just looking to shortening my sample bit-vecs while retaining as much of the original sample discrimination power, e.g. via Hamming distance.